# Rails Association (belongs_to) dilemma

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations, has-many, belongs-to

I have a User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :cards

end
```

and a Card model:

```
   class Card< ActiveRecord::Base

      belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => "owner_id"

   end
```

the card model also has an attribute called "owner_id", which I'd like to use in way like this:
Card.first.owner which will retrieve the User which owns that card

my problem as that, I know that rails will automagically connect the id's in the association but that doesnt happen.

in the CardController, rails get stuck in the create action on the line

```
@card=current_user.cards.new(params[:card])
```

and says `unknown attribute: user_id`

I've done `db:migrate` and it still won't work.

must I do as follows for it to work?

```
@card = Card.new(params[:card])
@card.owner_id=current_user.id
```

or am I missing something?

Comment: not sure this is the case but you have a typo in the word foreign

Comment: oops, it spells correctly in the code itself

Comment: there is a owner_id column which I want to use

Comment: I want to have the ability to get the owner of any card via @ card.owner. Also, I want to see all the cards of the user via @ user.cards

Comment: ok I get it. See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need a owner_id column for this. All you need is

```
class User
  has_many :cards
end
```

This will give you @user.cards

```
class Card
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "user_id"
end
```

This will give you @card.owner

Comment: If I do @card.owner after the card is created I get nil. Should I do anything special in a migration or in the controller?